# What is differance between WebBrowser and WebBrowserTask

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webbrowser-control

I am new to Windows Phone development. In one of my requirement I need to open the HTML pages to show some information and after complete reading this pages will return some data to my application, in such case WebBrowser is useful or WebBroserTask is useful?? Only WebBrowser.IsScriptEnabled is itself sufficient to achieve my target?? If possible please suggest me some code sample.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @ToniPetrina I have some html base slides, once user go through all the slides I want to add some points to users profile. But in that case html page need to return status data back to application.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get some data from the web page, you should use the `WebBrowser` control.

The `WebBrowserTask` puts you app in background and opens the specified page in Internet Explorer. Your app can't interact with it.

Comment: @OliverPayen thanks for details, is this the only on major difference!
How my HTML pages will communicate with my application. Can you please explain.

Comment: The WebBrowser control lets your app interact with the webpage, via the InvokeScript & ScriptNotify methods. InvokeScript allows your native app to execute JavaScript code in the webpage, and the webpage can communicate to your native app via ScriptNotify.